# RGB colour value as double - inaccuracy too big

Tags: c++, colors, double, precision, googletest

I'm currently reworking a nice Arduino library called RGBConverter ([original](https://github.com/ratkins/RGBConverter) and [my fork](https://github.com/aleksandaratanasov/RGBConverter)) for converting colour values in RGB colour space to others. I also want to add some testing using **gtest** because when it comes to colors represented as floating point numbers accuracy does matter. This applies not only to the color perception of the human eye but also for the various sensors that process light.

While creating a basic test case where I loop through a single RGB colour value component (red for example; from 0 to 10) as integer and convert it to its double representation I was greatly disappointed how inaccurate this procedure is.

Here is the code for my test case(s):

```
TEST(UnitCoversion, IntToDouble_single) {
  double x = 0.00000, x_res;
  int color = 0;
  for(; color < 10; color++) {
    printf("%d -> (expected: %.5f | actual: %.5f", color, x, x_res);
    RGBConverter::rgbIntToDouble_single(color, &x_res);
    EXPECT_NEAR(x, x_res, 0.0001);
    x+=0.004;
  }
}
```

And here is the function body of rgbIntToDouble(...):

```
void RGBConverter::rgbIntToDouble_single(int x, double *_x) {
  *_x = x/255.;
}
```

Needless to say the test fails:

```
The difference between x and x_res is 0.00015686274509803949, which exceeds 0.0001, where
x evaluates to 0.0080000000000000002,
x_res evaluates to 0.0078431372549019607, and
0.0001 evaluates to 0.0001.
3 -> (expected: 0.01200 | actual: 0.00784/RGBConverter/main.cpp:15: Failure
The difference between x and x_res is 0.00023529411764705924, which exceeds 0.0001, where
x evaluates to 0.012,
x_res evaluates to 0.011764705882352941, and
0.0001 evaluates to 0.0001.
4 -> (expected: 0.01600 | actual: 0.01176/RGBConverter/main.cpp:15: Failure
The difference between x and x_res is 0.00031372549019607898, which exceeds 0.0001, where
x evaluates to 0.016,
x_res evaluates to 0.015686274509803921, and
0.0001 evaluates to 0.0001.
5 -> (expected: 0.02000 | actual: 0.01569/RGBConverter/main.cpp:15: Failure
The difference between x and x_res is 0.00039215686274509873, which exceeds 0.0001, where
x evaluates to 0.02,
x_res evaluates to 0.019607843137254902, and
0.0001 evaluates to 0.0001.
6 -> (expected: 0.02400 | actual: 0.01961/RGBConverter/main.cpp:15: Failure
The difference between x and x_res is 0.00047058823529411847, which exceeds 0.0001, where
x evaluates to 0.024,
x_res evaluates to 0.023529411764705882, and
0.0001 evaluates to 0.0001.
7 -> (expected: 0.02800 | actual: 0.02353/RGBConverter/main.cpp:15: Failure
The difference between x and x_res is 0.00054901960784313822, which exceeds 0.0001, where
x evaluates to 0.028000000000000001,
x_res evaluates to 0.027450980392156862, and
0.0001 evaluates to 0.0001.
8 -> (expected: 0.03200 | actual: 0.02745/RGBConverter/main.cpp:15: Failure
The difference between x and x_res is 0.00062745098039215796, which exceeds 0.0001, where
x evaluates to 0.032000000000000001,
x_res evaluates to 0.031372549019607843, and
0.0001 evaluates to 0.0001.
9 -> (expected: 0.03600 | actual: 0.03137/RGBConverter/main.cpp:15: Failure
The difference between x and x_res is 0.00070588235294118118, which exceeds 0.0001, where
x evaluates to 0.036000000000000004,
x_res evaluates to 0.035294117647058823, and
0.0001 evaluates to 0.0001.
[  FAILED  ] UnitCoversion.IntToDouble_single (1 ms)
[----------] 1 test from UnitCoversion (1 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] UnitCoversion.IntToDouble_single

 1 FAILED TEST
```

As you can see I get pretty poor results after 2-3 decimal places after the floating point. I find this behaviour way too close to a float. However I am using doubles.

My question is: am I doing something wrong here? I do realize that summing up floating point numbers accumulates rounding error in time however here it starts at the very beginning! Using **0.1** or **0.01** as values for the *absoulte error* parameter of **EXPECT_NEAR** is hardly any testing... And errors with such magnitude do indeed affect the colour perception (tested it with a bunch of LEDs). How can I improve this if possible? If this is how it is I might as well switch to floats. At least memory wise it will be more efficient.

Comment: You calc something strange, for step 1 (not step 0), you have x == 0.004, and xres = 1. / 255., which of course not equal to 0.004 = 1 / 250, after that error just grow.

Comment: You mean `1/255`. And yes, I overlooked this **facepalm**. Can you please post is as answer so that I can accept it.